# Django: Custom form __init__() and ReverseMatch errors

Tags: django, forms, view

I have custom form code like this

```
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
start = forms.DateField(forms.DateInput())
end = forms.DateField(forms.DateInput())
type = forms.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ACTIVITY_CHOICES, default=RUNNING)

def clean(self):
    if 'start' in self.cleaned_data > 'end' in self.cleaned_data:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Popraw daty")
    else:
        pass
```

Problem is, when I try to load the page with that form, I get `TypeError at /reportform
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'`

That's connected with options to `type = forms.CharField` - but when I remove those, I get

```
NoReverseMatch at /reportform
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

This is my view that's trying to use this form:

```
def ReportRequest(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            usrname = request.user
            q = Training.objects.filter(user__in==usrname)
            q = Training.objects.filter(date__in>=form.cleaned_data['start'])
            q = Training.objects.filter(date__in<=form.cleaned_data['end'])
            q = Training.objects.filter(type__in==form.cleaned_data['type'])
            if q.count() == 0:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/notrainings/')
            avg_length = q.aggregate(Avg('length'))
            avg_distance = q.aggregate(Avg('distance'))
            avg_calories = q.aggregate(Avg('caloriesBurnt'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/report/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('reportform.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = ReportForm()
        return render_to_response('reportform.html',{'form':form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I don't know how to deal with this, and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default` is a valid parameter for a `Model`'s `CharField`.

For a form field, the valid parameter is `initial`

Try:

```
type = forms.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ACTIVITY_CHOICES, initial=RUNNING) #initial instead of default
```

Documentation on [`initial` here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial)

Now your reverse match is a totally different issue. (Woudl recommend digging into it, and creating a new question if you are still stuck - hint: the URL is not resolving to anything.)

Comment: I had to change `CharField` to `ChoiceField`, and it works now. Thanks for the help with `initial`. I guess somehow I've fixed the second error, it doesn't show now.